# Using conditional statements to bounce between colors opposed to popping

Tags: opengl, glsl, conditional-statements, vertex-shader

I've been reading an online article lately to learn the ropes of modern 3d OpenGL programming, and i'm getting stuck on one of the "independent practice" reviews. The question reads:

> In fragChangeColor.cpp, change it so that the fragment program bounces
>   between firstColor and secondColor, rather than popping from
>   secondColor back to first at the end of a loop. The
>   first-to-second-to-first transition should all happen within a single
>   fragLoopDuration time interval. In case you are wondering, GLSL
>   supports the if statement, as well as the ?: operator. For bonus
>   points however, do it without an explicit conditional statement; feel
>   free to use a sin or cos function to do this.

The trouble i'm having is using a conditional statement to bounce between the two colors, i have limited knowledge of the GLSL shader language. The following code slowly increases the color of the triangle until is hits it maximum, and pops the color back to white.

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform float fragLoopDuration;
uniform float time;

const vec4 firstColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
const vec4 secondColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

void main()
{
    float currTime = mod(time, fragLoopDuration); //makes the color pop from green to white once mod goes from 5 to 0 again
    float currLerp = currTime / fragLoopDuration;

    outputColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, currLerp);
}
```

somewhere in that code i need to include some sort of conditional statement, so that once the triangles color reaches it's maximum it will start to decrease the color until it reaches white, then the max color again and so on. How would i go about doing this? my initial guess would be using some sort of static bool if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overthink it. Here is your [function plot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJhYnMoc2luKHgpKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi00LjE1OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5NzUiLCI0LjE1OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5NzUiLCItMi41NTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTg3IiwiMi41NTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTg3Il19XQ--)

And code example:

```
uniform float time;

const vec4 firstColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
const vec4 secondColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

void main()
{
   float lerp = abs(sin(time));
   gl_FragColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, lerp);
}
```

You can test it online http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/ just copy-past code and press compile (small icon in top left corner of the source panel)

But left this block intact:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif
```

or it will not work.